# How do you control the forward movement of a sphere to be relative to a specific point on its body?

Tags: objects

I'm attempting to make a marble maze game on Blender, and trying to rotate the sphere so that forwards is always relative to a specific point on the sphere.  So far forwards is always in the y direction, and no matter how many rotation combinations I've tried, continues to persist in doing so.  Is there any way for the sphere to move forwards relative to a certain point on its face? As well as that, will this affect the cameras set up to follow the sphere?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Drivers may be an option, also see if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21387/how-can-we-animate-a-ball-rolling-over-a-path/21406#21406

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos , We're not taught to use coding during creation, just the main Blender application.  Sorry if it was a confusing question, I was trying to ask if there was a way to make a rolling sphere not go forwards in terms of along an axis, but to roll in the direction that a specific point is pointing towards.  For example, if I had four vertices on the sphere to signify north, south, east, and west, then the north vertex, no matter in which direction it's facing, would roll in that direction upon the press of the up arrow.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Drivers are part of the main application, but anyway, I think what you are looking for is motion in local coordinates, instead of global, no? In the motion actuator you can specify if the motion is global or local, I think. Not much into game engine myself