# how can i control the rotation of an object by direction it is moving in blender

Tags: animation

I parented a cone to empty object as shown in below attached image. Now whenever I move that empty object, I want the pointy side of cone to point (or rotate) towards the direction the empty is moving.
How can i do this in blender?[image]

Comment: Each frame in Blender is evaluated independently. The exception to the rule is simulations. So this means you can't access previous frame, and you can't calculate the velocity vector, only current position, unless you use a simulation. The simplest would be to use the simulation nodes in Blender 3.6 and later, as I do here: [Control shape keys with drivers to the speed of rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294231/60486)

Comment: this can be done by scripting, animation nodes (free blender add-on), geometry nodes

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using constraints?