# Showing the speed of Object or the speed of Camera (Speed Graph)

Tags: animation

I am amazed that there is no speed graph or a way to show the speed of the **Object Moving** (or the **Camera Moving**). Can you guys tell me the way to show it ??

I have checked the old posts and there are some Script/Python in there. But I have NO IDEA how to use them. I never learned code, I never learned Python, I don't know how to use Script on Blender. Please tell me step by step as if I am a baby.

Thanks a lot for your help

PS: there is a **Geometry Nodes** to calculate the length of Curve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NbCwGYEjWc&t=221s . And I find it very helpful. It would be great if there were a **Geometry Nodes** for speed.

Comment: You can measure speed, acceleration, jerk etc. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294231/60486

Comment: The suggested duplicate does seem to answer your question quite comprehensively. If you disagree, go ahead and edit, linking back there, explaining why it doesn't quite work for you, and we can re-open for you..