Take position values geometry nodes and apply them on an object outside of geometry nodes
I am trying to figure out how to take values that I have exposed in the group output in geometry nodes/stored as named attributes and take these values and use them elsewhere in a different object as it's transform.

Here I have the values that are in the geometry nodes spreadsheet, so I know that they are being written, though I am having difficulty taking these out of geometry nodes and on direct XYZ transformations on a different object. The goal is to have a camera follow the center of the bounding box of the geometry nodes, and my workaround was to have an object get moved to the center of said bounding box with these values.

In the modifier information I can also see that the named attributes are also being exposed, though I am unsure where to go form here.

You can use a vertex parenting technique: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294231/60486

(Using Blender 4.2.1)

This proposal is an adaptation of the post Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset.

Approach
The overall objective is to track with a camera the center of the bounding box of an object. One approach is to add a third object (named "Coder" thereafter) between the object to track and the tracking camera. Its purpose is to make the communication between both

by computing the bounding box center (receive)
by providing this position to the camera (send)

Coder setup

1. In Object Mode, add an object made of one vertex using the menu entry Add>Mesh>Single Vert>Add Single Vert. Its position is irrelevant.
2. Add a GeometryNodes modifier to this object, with the above graph.
3. The object to track (named "Suzanne" here) is provided through the GN modifier input parameters.
4. Its bounding box center coordinates are computed from its geometry recovered through an Object Info node whose Transform Space is set to Relative.
5. The single point of the "Coder" is moved with a Set Position node to the location computed at step 4 (see the light orange dot in the 3D Viewport). It is to notice that only the position of the vertex is updated. The object's origin remains at its creation location defined at step 1. To use this vertex as a moving point in the definition of a constraint, the documentation explains that "(...) the constraint will target the median point of this vertex group instead of the object’s origin".
6. Consequently in Edit Mode, in the Object Data Properties panel, add a Vertex Group (named "Coder") and Assign to this group the single vertex after selecting it. With only one point, the group median point is this point.
Camera setup

(In this figure, the "Coder" is displayed as a black dot at the center of the camera view)
7. Add a Damped Track constraint to the camera. Set the Target to the "Coder" object created at step 1, then the Vertex Group to the "Coder" group created at step 6.
8. Adjust the Track Axis.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Thank you, this got me to the point I wish to be, however I was wondering if there is a way to have the camera automatically adjust it's focal length to always have the full bounding box in view? I tried some vector math using the centre point of the nearest edge the camera is looking at, combining this with the centre of the bounding box and using the distance option in the vector math node, however I am not sure where to go from there using the provided float, if this is even the correct route to take at all.

I am working on an other proposal including the camera focus length. I will post it on your following question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/324189/zoom-out-camera-using-geometry-nodes-value. I hope to have time to format it by the end of the week.
