Zoom out camera using geometry nodes value
I am looking for a way to have a camera in my scene get zoomed out using a (or multiple) value(s) retrieved from geometry nodes. Sadly I can not use the method used here due to the nature of my approach. The object generated in the scene has to stay the same scale while the camera zooms out, either through the usage of adjusting the focal length or moving it backwards in the XY transformation.
I have attempted to expose a value that calculates the distance between the closest edge to the camera and the center of the bounding box in the group output, but can't find a method to connect this to my camera.

Is it possible to achieve this through the usage of drivers or another method I might be missing here?

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos The linked duplicate question answers how to get camera data into Geometry Nodes, but the question here is how to get Geometry Nodes data into the camera...

Isn't it just the reverse? Copy the value as a driver from the node tree into the camera property? I just tested, it sort of works, but it isn't updating real time, for some reason. Also doesn't apply for the attributes case. Reopened

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos you can use geonodes inputs (default values) as driver source, but not dynamically calculated outputs (even if those are single values), so you need to output the values in a way visible to a driver, e.g. by a position of a vertex, to which you hook an empty, and then the driver can read the empty's position: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294231/60486

@MarkusvonBroady That would make a great answer. ;)

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
(NB: this answer is under writing...)
Objectives
There are two objectives:

To center the camera view inside the frame bounding the targeted object.
To adjust the camera focal length such that the targeted object is filling the camera view.


This animation illustrates how the view axis and focal length of the camera are evolving while its viewpoint and its orientation are modified.
Analysis
Let $O$ be the camera position, $T$ the central point the camera is looking at, $\vec{n}$ the camera view axis, $F$ the frame bounding the targeted object (i.e. the orange rectangle displayed on the right side of the above illustration).

$T$ is defined as the center of $F$ ; so $T$ is a function of $F$, $T=g(F)$.
$F$ is perpendicular to $\vec{n}$ with $\vec{n} = \vec{OT} / \|\vec{OT} \|$; so $F$ is a function of $T$, $F=h(T)$.

From Blender point of view, there is a circular dependency between $T$ and $F$. From a mathematical point of view, $T$ is a fixed point of the function $g \circ h$, i.e. $T=g \circ h(T)$. Assuming $T$ known, $g \circ h(T)$ is computed in two steps:

$F=h(T)$: The points of the targeted object are projected on the plane defined by $T$ and $\vec{n}$. Beware it is not a parallel projection, but a central projection of center $O$.
$T=g(F)$: $T$ is computed as the center of the bounding box of these projected points. The orientation of the bounding box is defined by the camera.

Approach
In numerical analysis, fixed-point iteration is a method of computing fixed points of a function. Let $i$ be the iteration counter. $T^{i+1}$, an intermediate value of $T$, is computed as $T^{i+1} = g \circ h(T^i)$. It is expected that $T^i$ converges towards $T$ for a given accuracy in a finite number of iterations. The recursion is initialized with $T^0$ set at the center of the targeted object bounding box.
In the frame of this question, this basic iteration process can be diverging when the distance between the camera and the targeted object is small compared to the object size (for more details, see Stationary iterative methods). To recover convergence, a relaxation technique is implemented, as a linear combination of the previous value $T^i$ with the new evaluation $T^{*}=g \circ h(T^i)$. Let $\alpha$ be the relaxation coefficient with $\alpha \in [0:1]$. $T^{i+1}$ is defined as:
$$ T^{i+1} = \alpha \times T^i + (1-\alpha) \times T^{*}$$

This figure illustrates how the camera view (bounded by a black dash line) is converging with $\alpha=0.2$ for a configuration that is diverging otherwise without relaxation (i.e. $\alpha=0$). For demonstration purpose, the projected faces are superimposed in wire mode, and the "empty" space around is filled with rectangular faces (NB: the resulting grid is chosen slightly larger than the camera view for aesthetic reasons). After 1 iteration, "Suzanne" right eye is out of frame ; $T$ has to be moved to the left side. After 2 iterations, this eye is in frame, but the tip of its left hear is out of frame ; $T$ has to be moved back to the right side. Next iterations show such damped oscillations until convergence is reached.
Resources

Blender file: (Blender 4.2.1+)
To track only the center of the object bounding box, see: Take position values geometry nodes and apply them on an object outside of geometry nodes
The communication between GeometryNodes and Drivers is derived from the post Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset.


Parts and chain of dependencies
To avoid circular dependencies, four "parts" are chained. These are described thereafter from the root, without dependency, to the most dependent.


Ouput (no dependency): The section Format of the Output Properties panel is defining the rendered image Resolution. The ratio between X and Y values fixes the camera view aspect ratio.
Observer (driven by Output): This object carrying the GeometryNodes modifier is computing and encoding the position of $T$, the camera Focal Length, the camera Sensor Width and the camera orientation. The focal length is adjusted to accommodate the width and height of the projected object. Thus the rendered image aspect ratio is required from the Output.
CameraData (driven by Observer): Through its position, this object is exposing the camera Focal Length and Sensor Width parameters. A Copy Location constraint is fixing its position from data coded by the Observer.
Camera (driven by Observer and CameraData): This object is a child of the Observer, which is controlling its position this way. Besides Damped Track and Locked Track constrains are fixing its orientation towards $T$ from data coded by the Observer. Eventually, drivers based on the CameraData object position are setting values in the Lens and Camera sections of the Camera Data Properties panel.

Setup
Observer
The Observer is a Mesh object made of only 3 vertices, from an edited Cube primitive for example. The position of these vertices is irrelevant as it is fixed by the GeometryNodes modifier. Each of these vertices is assigned to one Vertex Group. The first one named "Target" is coding the position of $T$. The second one named "CameraData" is coding the Focal Length (as X) and the Sensor Width (as Y) of the camera. The last one named "Top" is coding the position of the center of the upper edge of the camera view frame.
The input parameters of the GeometryNodes modifier are:

Object: the targeted object.
Sensor Width (mm): the size of the sensor determining the focal length of the camera.
Aspect Ratio: used to compute the height of the camera sensor from its width.
Iterations: number of fixed-point iterations.
Relaxation: relaxation coefficient $\alpha$.

CameraData
The CameraData is an Empty object whose initial position is irrelevant as it is fixed by the Copy Location constraint.
Camera
The Camera is a Camera object whose initial position is collocated with the origin of the Observer. It is parented to the Observer. Contrary to a classical setup, the viewpoint, the view orientation and scale are set by manipulating the Observer, not the Camera directly.
GeometryNodes modifier
Convergence and encoding
The following graph is attached to the Observer.

1. The fixed-point iterations with relaxation are performed by a Repeat Zone. Only the "Target" item is recycled ; as input, it is equal to $T^{i}$ ; as output, it is equal to $T^{i+1}$.
2. The "Frame" Group Node is computing $T^{*}=g \circ h(T^i)$ from the projection of the targeted object. It is also returning the "Top" position of the frame, as well as its dimensions, "Width" and "Height".
3. $T^0$ is computed as the average of the Min and Max positions returned by a Bounding Box node applied to the targeted object. It is to notice that the Transform Space of the Object Info node providing its Geometry is set to Relative. Consequently, subsequent vector geometry is performed with the point $O$ set at the origin of the Observer.
4. To encode ... (to be continued)
Computation

Mathematics
