# How to Dribble soccer ball?

Tags: animation

Im trying to dribble a soccer ball. This character can run thru animations i got from mixamo. How do i make the ball movement realistic when hes running with the ball. Is there some kind of physics i use?

? [image]

Comment: The short answer is no. You would need to learn rigging and animate the character. While you can use rigid body physics on the ball to let it bounce on the ground, making the player dribble is a lot more complex. If you really want to learn this, I'd suggest watching character rigging tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: Thats fine but how would i rig the ball? Rigging character with riggify is simple enough but how would i rig the ball. Seems just keyframes and move the ball it seem?

Comment: It's a trade off between realism and control. If you want to use physics you could try to make the ball a rigid body. The floor should be a passive rigid body for collision. I'd add his legs as passive collision object as well. Then you could experiment and let him kick the ball for real. This simulation based approach may be hard to control though. Since I'm not the most experienced person when it comes to animation, somebody else might have a better idea.

Comment: Using keyframes makes it easier to control, however it may require quite a bit of work to make the motion look realistic.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21387/how-can-we-animate-a-ball-rolling-over-a-path?rq=1 is a good starting point for rigging the ball, but you will most likely need to tweak things for kicks.

Comment: How about using unity and writing a script where the ball is attached to the player as long he reached it and make the ball roll away the. Slow down on the direction of the player distinction creating the illusion of dribbling.