# How to rig a BB-8 Model?

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers

[image]I want to make a rig for this BB-8 unit so that when it moves on X or Y axis it can rotate automatically even if it moves on both axis (on diagonal direction) most of tutrorials i saw works in case it moves on 1 axis only and doesn't rotate correctly when it moves diagonally please or mention other tutorial that fixes this problem |

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because that is impossible to do. If the movement is constrained to single axis, there is only 1 way to reach the rigs pose and so the movement(rotation) can be computed. In XY space you could travel infinite amount of ways each different distance to your pose position and so there is no way to know the exact rotations. The only way you can have this work is through simulation, computing it on frame-by-frame basis by a script. You can't compute the rotations from the rest pose and posed pose alone.

Comment: thanks for your reply

is there any script do you know to make this happen?

Comment: If you can have a curve path, on which would this be rigged, then yes, if the path is known, the rotations can be computed. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21387/how-can-we-animate-a-ball-rolling-over-a-path/21406

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: I am not familiar with such a script, but it could work very similarly to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29184/7777. The core is there - you know the current and last frame location and from there you drive the rotations with a bit of math.

Comment: I describe the problem you are facing in more detail here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111259/7777